# calling PhP function in JavaScript returns white screen

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, function

Before anyone complains: i know that javascript is clientside and php is serverside.
I need to call a php-function within my javascript (both in the same file). i used

```
document.write("<?php add(); ?>");
```

which calls the function from php like it should. the main problem is that the page turns white (like when i call echo "";), which should not happen. i tested with an completly empty test();, ending up in the same problem.

to answer the question why i want to call the function: i need to update a sql table on pressing a key. as far as i know its impossible to make a keylistener in php and too unsafe to use sql in javascript.

greetings and thx for help

Comment: if you get a white page, then there is most likely a php error. turn on php error reporting to figure it out.

Comment: you can't run php like that

Comment: to call php function use ajax and return ajax result. Then processing it according to your needs.

Comment: The way to make a php function run is by sending a http request to the server.  There are many ways to do this...(link, form submit, ajax, request an image, request a javascript file) and so on.

Comment: ye thx for the answers. i didnt understand ajax till now, but reading your comments it seems to be the only way so i found http://www.keyboardninja.eu/webdevelopment/jquery-ajax-call-tutorial
which explains ajax very easy (for the point someone got the same problem like me: read it)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `document.write` at any other moment than during page load, it will wipe out your document and replace it with whatever you pass as argument. From your question it seems you run this code in an event handler,  like for the `keypressed` event. In this case, it is expected behaviour of `document.write` that your page turns white. Don't use it there.

What you need to do is identify where in your document you want to insert content, more precisely, at which element, and provide content to it. You can use several methods for this, like `.innerHTML`, but not `document.write`.

Secondly, you should understand that when you pass an argument that has `php` generated values in it, that these arguments are calculated at the moment `php` generates the page, and not when the corresponding `javascript` executes. At that latter moment no call to `php` takes place, as `php` already did it's job during the generation of the page.

If you want to execute a `php` function **at the moment of** an event in the browser, you should issue an `http` request to the server. This can be done by submitting a form, by navigating to a different `url`, or by issuing an `ajax` call. In these cases the server receives a request, and `php` can be executed, which will again generated content and send it back to the browser.

You can find example `ajax` code on the internet, for example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_examples.asp).